# With what units I need to call minServer() in CCOptim library to get correct values?

Tags: java

I am using [CCOptim](http://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~chanwyea/ccoptim/doc/html/) library to calculate minimum servers required using a below given function

```
`minServer(double arrivalRate, double serviceRate, double awt, double slTarget)`.
```

I have values of parameters in seconds( like arrivalRate 100 calls/second). But when I am calling this function with values in seconds, it is returning incorrect number of servers required.

(Basically I want to verify weather values calculated by some other system are correct or not).

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That is, show us your code and the output you're getting, and explain why the output isn't what you expect.

Comment: @Steve minServer(10, 60,60, 0.8) is expected to give 602 as per calculator given here https://www-ens.iro.umontreal.ca/~chanwyea/erlang/erlangC.html but returning 1. Units for all values is seconds